# Understand closure in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In cluster modes, how to write a closure function `f` to let every worker access the copy of variable `N`.

```
N=5
lines=sc.parallelize(['early radical', 'french revolution','pejorative way', 'violent means'])
def f1(line):
    return line[:N]
l=lines.map(f1)
l.collect()
```

I am trying to experiment to find out whether my understanding is right. In my example, `f1` works in local mode.

I don't have any cluster and I really want to know if it will work in cluster modes? In other word, can worker access variable `N`, which is defined outside `f1` but used inside `f1` in the driver node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In other word, can worker access variable N, which is defined outside f1 but used inside f1 in the driver node.

Kind of.

- There is no shared memory between nodes, including workers and drivers. So worker cannot access the variable which lives on the drive.
- However when this code is compute, Spark will analyze `f1` definition, determine variables present in the closure, and serialize these along with `f1`.

  So when the function is actually invoked a local copy of the parent environment will be present in the scope.

Keeping these two things in mind we can answer the question:

> I don't have any cluster and I really want to know if it will work in cluster modes?

Yes, it will work just fine on the distributed cluster.

However if you tried to modify the object passed through closure, the changes won't be propagated and will affect only local copies (in other words, don't even try).

Comment: To be specifically, do you mean that (1) `f1` works fine in cluster mode. (2) Every closure sent to worker from driver do include variable `N`(Here variable `N` means the copy of variable `N` in driver node)?

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer for me!